# Can you tell me what's wrong with my Python script?(2.7.14)

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I type in 30 it says it's incorrect, what am i doing wrong?

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
print '%s/%s/%s %s:%s:%s' % (now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
print raw_input('Welcome, first you need to confirm you can do math. Press ENTER to continue.')
answer = raw_input("What is 9 + 21?:")

if answer == 30:
    print 'Access granted.'
else:
    print 'Incorrect.'
```

Comment: `answer` is a string and you are checking for an integer, thus it will always fail

Comment: use `answer = int(raw_input("What is 9 + 21:"))`